# SoycDashboard$FormatException on GWT Compilation

Tags: gwt

I´m experiencing this error when compiling my GWT project on GWT 2.5.1 version.

The same project compiles withou error on Windows, but when I thy to compile on linux this issue is reported:

```
 [exec] [INFO]    Validating units:
 [exec] [INFO]       Ignored 5 units with compilation errors in first pass.
 [exec] [INFO] Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
 [exec] [INFO]    Compiling 6 permutations
 [exec] [INFO]       Compiling permutation 0...
 [exec] [INFO]       Compiling permutation 1...
 [exec] [INFO]       [ERROR] Unexpected internal compiler error
 [exec] [INFO] com.google.gwt.soyc.SoycDashboard$FormatException
 [exec] [INFO]      at com.google.gwt.soyc.SoycDashboard$2.accountForSize(SoycDashboard.java:514)
 [exec] [INFO]      at com.google.gwt.soyc.SoycDashboard$2.recordSize(SoycDashboard.java:583)
 [exec] [INFO]      at com.google.gwt.soyc.SoycDashboard$2.startElement(SoycDashboard.java:499)
 [exec] [INFO]      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
 [exec] [INFO]      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
 [exec] [INFO]      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:356)
 [exec] [INFO]      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2786)
 [exec] [INFO]      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
 [exec] [INFO]      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
 [exec] [INFO]      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
 [exec] [INFO]      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
 [exec] [INFO]      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
 [exec] [INFO]      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
 [exec] [INFO]      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
 [exec] [INFO]      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:648)
 [exec] [INFO]      at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:332)
 [exec] [INFO]      at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
 [exec] [INFO]      at com.google.gwt.soyc.SoycDashboard.readSizeMaps(SoycDashboard.java:360)
 [exec] [INFO]      at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.makeSoycArtifacts(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:1233)
 [exec] [INFO]      at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.compilePermutation(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:514)
 [exec] [INFO]      at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.UnifiedAst.compilePermutation(UnifiedAst.java:134)
 [exec] [INFO]      at com.google.gwt.dev.CompilePerms.compile(CompilePerms.java:195)
 [exec] [INFO]      at com.google.gwt.dev.ThreadedPermutationWorkerFactory$ThreadedPermutationWorker.compile(ThreadedPermutationWorkerFactory.java:49)
 [exec] [INFO]      at com.google.gwt.dev.PermutationWorkerFactory$Manager$WorkerThread.run(PermutationWorkerFactory.java:73)
 [exec] [INFO]      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 [exec] [INFO]       [ERROR] Unrecoverable exception, shutting down
 [exec] [INFO] com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
 [exec] [INFO]      at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationProblemReporter.logAndTranslateException(CompilationProblemReporter.java:96)
 [exec] [INFO]      at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.compilePermutation(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:539)
 [exec] [INFO]      at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.UnifiedAst.compilePermutation(UnifiedAst.java:134)
 [exec] [INFO]      at com.google.gwt.dev.CompilePerms.compile(CompilePerms.java:195)
 [exec] [INFO]      at com.google.gwt.dev.ThreadedPermutationWorkerFactory$ThreadedPermutationWorker.compile(ThreadedPermutationWorkerFactory.java:49)
 [exec] [INFO]      at com.google.gwt.dev.PermutationWorkerFactory$Manager$WorkerThread.run(PermutationWorkerFactory.java:73)
 [exec] [INFO]      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 [exec] [INFO]       [ERROR] Not all permutation were compiled , completed (1/6)
```

**SOLUTION**

After testing and debugging GWT Compilation process it appears to be a SAXParser problem. I´ve specified the default SAXParser  for gwt compilation jvm using -Djavax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl and the issue was solved.

Comment: You are receiving a format exception, could it be, that you are running into a localization issue? Date/Time/Number format?

Comment: Well, I found the reason for com.google.gwt.soyc.SoycDashboard$FormatException. The problem is that when reading "SizeMaps" from stories.xml the java to javascript compilation process the "type" attribute at one of the size elements from sizemap is "6ethod" istead of "method". I´m trying to discover the reason, but for now, no answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

After testing and debugging GWT Compilation process it appears to be a SAXParser problem. I´ve specified the default SAXParser for gwt compilation jvm using -Djavax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl and the issue was solved.